# Hide table rows for @media print

Tags: jquery, css, printing, html-table, media

I have a table of data and each row has a checkbox that when checked indicates that the user would like that row to be included in the printed table. When the row is checked JQuery adds a print class to the :

```
$("td .checkbox").click(function(e){
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#tr-"+this.id).addClass("print");
    } else {
        $("#tr-"+this.id).removeClass("print");
    }
});
```

Edit: Adding HTML to show the id and class for answer below...

```
<tr id="tr-print-0" class="search-line-item-0 print">
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data...</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="print-0" name="print-0"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr-print-1" class="search-line-item-1">...
<tr id="tr-print-2" class="search-line-item-0">...
```

Then in my CSS file I have @media print{} which sets the row's display to none or block.

```
tr.search-line-item-0, tr.search-line-item-1 {
    display: none;
}

tr.search-line-item-0.print, tr.search-line-item-1.print {
    display: block;
}
```

The issue is when you print the page only the rows with display:block show up, which is the intended behavior, but it looks like each row is being rendered inside of the first column (the first `<th>` spans the `<tr>` and then all the other `<th>`s have nothing below them). Only tested in Chrome and Firefox so far and the issue is the same in both browsers.

The goal is to have a quick way of checking rows and printing them without opening other windows or using an iframe. So if anyone knows an alternate solution that would work too :)

Comment: Please post a complete example (HTML document with CSS) that demonstrates the issue. You are now e.g. referring to `th` elements, but the code snippets contain no such element. Note that you should not set `display: block` on `tr`, as a `tr` in normal situation is supposed to have `display: table-row`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, thanks display: table-row did the trick. If you want to post that I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `display: block`, set `display: table-row` to get normal rendering as a row of the table.

Answer (score 2):

Your selectors done match up between your CSS and Javascript. In your javascript you are calling the rows by id and in the CSS you are looking at the row with a class.

```
$("td .checkbox").click(function(e){
   var $row = $("tr.search-line-item-"+this.id);
   if (this.checked) {
      $row.addClass("print");
   } else {
      $row.removeClass("print");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit the id naming convention could have been clearer, added HTML to my question showing how it's setup ('tr' is part of the id). The 'print' class definitely gets added (I can see it in webkit), and only the rows with that class are visible when you print, the problem is they don't render correctly.